# how to add a specific value from a list box in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, listbox, listboxitems

[image]

how can i retrieve the total price only from this listbox and then total up in a textbox??
this is the code to add data to the listbox

```
Private Sub cbitem_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cbitem.SelectedIndexChanged
    If cbitem.SelectedIndex < 0 Then Return
    Dim price = Convert.ToDecimal(items(cbitem.SelectedIndex, 1))
    txtitemprice.Text = price
End Sub

Private Sub btnadd_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnadd.Click
    Dim price = Convert.ToDecimal(txtitemprice.Text)
    Dim quantity = Convert.ToInt32(txtquantity.Text)
    Dim totalprice As Integer = price * quantity
    lstorder.Items.Add(cbitem.SelectedItem & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & price & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & quantity & vbTab & vbTab & totalprice)
End Sub
```

Comment: There is more than one way to display data in a list box, you should show how that data got in there.  A better choice would have been a DataGridView - it is a real grid so it have actual cells.  I suspect you are saving strings which means looping them and chopping them up to get at the data

Comment: @plutonix the data got in from textboxes and i cant use a datagridview.

Comment: Not enough details.  There is **more than one way to show data in a listbox** - we cant tell from a picture what the code looks like.  Details are important.  It is almost impossible to ask a good question here without showing code related to the question

Comment: a) not a lot of error checking thee - it will crash if there is nothing selected in `cbitem` b) why not look up the item selected in your array? c) controls are meant to display data not manage it, I would use a collection representing the Shopping cart d) as is, you added stings, so loop thru the items collection, split it, any/all of the last elements that can be converted to decimal (?), do so and add to a `total` var.

Comment: I understand the question .  `d` in the list explains how. Break it down into steps and make some effort.  You wont learn much being spoon fed answers

Comment: @Plutonix if i take the data directly from totalprice and display it in another textbox for the total of total prices would it be better ?

Comment: You could update the total at the same time they select make a CBO selection. That will work as long as they cant remove an item.  You should also add `Option Strict On` to the top of your form file.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that you have two controls : ListBox1 and TextBox1.

```
' Initialise the textBox to 0    
TextBox1.Text = 0

' Insert values in your listbox
 ListBox1.Items.Add(1)
 ListBox1.Items.Add(2)
 ListBox1.Items.Add(3)
 ListBox1.Items.Add(4)

 ' For each item in your ListBox
 For i As Integer = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
      TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text + ListBox1.Items(i)
 Next
```

For your work, you have to get the price of the current item and multiply it with it's quantity. Or you can sum each item of the totalPrice column.